# PHP regular expression if something is there or not

Tags: php, regex

I am working with regular expressions, and I have this block of code:

```
 $find = "/jsfile\.js?[0-9]*</";
 $switch = 'jsfile.js?version=' . $version . '<';
 $replace = preg_replace($find, $switch, $data);
```

My problem is that my JavaScript file now has `?version=<number>`. Now, if I run this script again, it will break.

Is there a way to say, using regular expressions, in my `$find` string that `?version=` may or may not be there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$find = '/jsfile\.js\?(version=)?[0-9]*</';
```

`?` makes the preceding element optional, and parentheses create a group, so `(version=)?` means "optionally match `version=`".  Note that I also escaped the `?` from earlier in the regular expression, since you want this to match a literal `?` and not make the `s` optional.

In addition, I switched from double to single quotes to ensure the escaping works properly, if you were to use double quotes you would want to escape each backslash, for example:

```
$find = "/jsfile\\.js\\?(version=)?[0-9]*</";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an optional subpattern: `(?:version=)?`

Answer (score 0):

```
$find = '/jsfile\.js\?(version=)?[0-9]*</';
```

Something like this should do..

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern instead:

```
$find = '~jsfile\.js\?\K(?>version=)?\d++(?=<)~';
$switch = 'version='. $version;
$replace = preg_replace($find, $switch, $data);
```